# External Data In iOS app

Tags: ios

We will be using a JSON feed for an iOS app. I have a few questions in how to design for an external data source.

1. Should the external data source be cached in core data for a set period of time and then refetched when cache expires?
2. What is a general strategy with dealing with external data sources? (In terms of caching/performance)

Comment: I think those are decisions that depend strictly on your project, not on something specific to iOS...

Answer (score 0):

If the app is very data heavy you'll probably want to cache things using Core Data. You can store some sort of hash attribute to compare with the server to see if the cache is still valid and refresh it if it isn't (the hash should be generated and sent over from the server when data is fetched).

Depending on the complexity of your app. You may want to use something some set of third party classes or a framework. Something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) gives a lot of shortcuts on top of Apple's connection code, and [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) provides data synchronization with an external server(although it takes some setup).